# How can I pass in parameters from one to another ViewModel for its View to use?

Tags: c#, user-interface, mvvm, avaloniaui, avalonia

I have an app that should display data based on variables from parameters received from calls of the ViewModel.

I have noticed two places in which the ViewModel gets called from, one is the intended call by the parent ViewModel for displaying the View of the child ViewModel with the help of `ViewLocator.cs`. Another is the `DataContext` required by the View to enable data binding.

Former: [`ParentViewModel.cs`]

```cs
public ParentViewModel()
{
    UserControlContent = new ChildViewModel(genericParameter: "actual parameter");
}
```

Latter: [`ChildView.axaml.cs`]

```cs
public ChildView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new ChildViewModel(genericParameter: "not the parameter I want");
}
```

So I want to pass in the `"actual parameter"` as shown above for show in the resulting View. I expect the final view to look like this:

[image: image of an app window showing the text "actual parameter".]

But in reality I get this:

[image: image of an app window showing the text "not the parameter I want".]

So, how can I work around this and get the View to display the right data?

Appreciate any input!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, only the call from the `ParentViewModel` is required. `DataContext` under `ChildView` can be removed and the correct parameter can be used.

Thanks to the answer [here](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/discussions/9981#discussioncomment-4688679) for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some fundamental misunderstandings of MVVM.

Firstly, you have two `ChildViewModel` instances.

So calls made in your `ParentViewModel` on the `UserControlContent` instance of the view model will never be reflected in the UI as the `ChildView` creates a new instance of the `ChildViewModel` itself and then uses this instance for as it's `DataContext`.

You should make use of some form of IoC and DI your dependencies.

MVVM discourages the use of manual view model creation through the `new` keyword.

Unless there is a very specific use case, try to keep some relationship between the UI structure and your view models as flat as possible.

By this I mean if there is a use case where the parent view model needs the same things as the child view mode. It may make sense to flatten and merge those two view models.

This in turn simplifies the VMs themselves and the bindings.